# how to hide salesforce email address?

Tags: apex-email-service

I have a requirement where...

my company works for different clients(like Orange, Apple, Avacado,etc.) and it's customers. We send requests and quotes to different customers on behalf of different clients. All this is taken care by Apex Code.

We have setup a Email Service where we get a long email id from salesforce which is used in Apex Coding. The outgoing emails from system now has sender email ID looking something like `AgentOne@Orange.com`, `AgentTwo@Apple.com`,etc., This was achieved by adding some custom logic to add display names (AgentOne@Orange.com, AgentTwo@Apple.com,etc.,) which can also be done by [Org wide addresses like suggested here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=orgwide_email.htm).

When Customer is trying to reply to emails sent from system with Display labels mentioned above and click reply, they see the long salesforce email id `reply_to_email@gsdfdsckassdfasdf324adfds4weqwx8wnewreweq2o0p.c-3vdsdfeam.cs14.apex.sandbox.salesforce.com`.

Is there a way to Hide/Add some display name to cover-up that salesforce email id when customer is replying?

Comment: @crmprogdev Can you share your apex code? I'm actually trying to achieve the opposite of what you are, and maybe if we cross reference our code we can find the difference that will fix both of our problems.

Comment: Oops, I mean @Win4frndz

Comment: @Jwok, since you're trying to do the opposite, I think the answer below I created & deleted, assuming it's visible to you should do what you're asking.

Comment: @crmprogdev I can't see the answer you mentioned. Can you re-post it?

Comment: @Jwok, I've undeleted my answer. It doesn't solve the OP's question which is partially related to spoofing. But, it does allow for changing the "from" label when using several different Org Wide Email addresses for users handling cases. To solve the OP's question, one would need to use Exchange routing for their clients because of CANSPAM and other client email routing verification.

Answer (score 1):

This answer doesn't completely answer the OP's question, but it does allow for changing labels of emails being sent by users responding to Cases. The OP's question is partly an issue of legalities and source verification that occurs when phishing emails are sent which cannot be avoided. One would need to use "Sent on behalf of of xxxxx by yyyyy" to work around this for clarity.

Here's the remainder of my original answer on how to handle sending emails for Cases by users from different Org Wide Email Addresses:

To do what you're asking, you'd need to use the EmailMessage object and set the following:

```
  FromName = nameString;
  FromAddress = emailAddressString;
```

Where `nameString` is the name or label you want to use to associate with the `emailAddressString`.